# How to use tolower with lambda function in map? C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, lambda, transform

I want to change all the words stored in a map to lower case. with lambda function and transform, how should I do that?

```
std::map <string, int> M;
std::map<string, int> M1;

std::transform(M.begin(), M.end(), M1.begin(),
         [](pair<const string, int> const & p) { ::tolower(p.first); });
```

Comment: You may not change keys. You should copy the original map in some other map.

Comment: since the `string` in your map is the **key**, when accessing the elements in your map, you only have `const` access (notice the `const string` in your pair), so you can't edit them. You'll have to create a new map with the lower case keys

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  Like this? I have edited my question.

Comment: Just use a normal iteration over the items to fill M1. Nothing fancy needed here.

Answer (score 2):

You can't edit **keys** in a `map`, so you'll have to **create a new map**

Something along the lines of:

- **iterate** over the values in your map
- take a **copy** of the key
- **transform** it to lowercase
- **insert** it into your result map:

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> map = {{ "HELLO", 1 }, { "WORLD", 2 }};

    std::cout << "before:\n";
    for (auto& kv : map)
    {
        std::cout << '\t' << kv.first << ":" << kv.second << '\n';
    }

    // create a new map with lowercase keys
    std::map<std::string, int> out;
    std::for_each(map.begin(), map.end(), [&](auto& kv)
        {
            std::string lower;
            std::transform(kv.first.begin(), kv.first.end(), std::back_inserter(lower), tolower);
            out[lower] = kv.second;
        });

    std::cout << "after:\n";
    for (auto& kv : out)
    {
        std::cout << '\t' << kv.first << ":" << kv.second << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
before:
    HELLO:1
    WORLD:2
after:
    hello:1
    world:2
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciated. But I'm trying to learn lambda here. Can you please show me how to deal with M and M1 without for loop?

Comment: @Dorothy I've changed the creation of the map to use `std::for_each` with a lambda. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

`std::transform`assigns the result of the functor to elements in the destination range. This means that the destination iterator must be the start of range with same size as the input range. In your example, the destination is an empty map. The transform essentially is the following loop:

```
std::map <string, int> M;
std::map<string, int> M1;

for(auto i=M.begin(), j=M1.begin(); i != M.end(); ++i,++j)
{
    *j = f(*i);
}
```

Decrementing `j` is illegal for empty containers, and doesn't really make sense for a map since you cannot change the key.

What you can see from this code is that your lambda is also incorrect. It should transform one (key value) pair into an object of the target type. In your case, the target type is the same.

You either have to resize the destination container before, e.g. by calling `resize` if it was a vector, or use an iterator which adapts the assignment to `map::insert`. The STL provides adaptors for this:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
std::map <std::string, int> M;
std::map<std::string, int> M1;

std::transform(M.begin(), M.end(), std::inserter(M1, M1.begin()),
               [](std::pair<const std::string, int> const & p) 
{ 
    std::string lowercase;
    std::transform( p.first.begin(), p.first.end(), 
                    std::back_inserter(lowercase),
                    [](auto c) {return std::tolower(c);} );

    return std::make_pair(lowercase, p.second); 
});

return 0;
}
```

Comment: make_pair ? do I need to include something else?

Comment: @Dorothy I don't know what you include in your program :-) `std::make_pair` is in `utility`. You also need `iterator` for the inserter.

Comment: I included both. It says "no matching function for call to 'tolower' ".

Comment: @Dorothy Sorry, you are right. `std::tolower`only works with characters, not with strings. You either have to implement one yourself, or use some library function. I will update the code in the answer. `std::tolower` is in `cctype`.

Comment: Can you create a new string like that? Error shows "no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >')"

Comment: @Dorothy I've changed the example to a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use exactly `std::transform` then you can use the following approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>


int main ()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> m1 = { { "FIRST", 1 }, { "SECOND", 2 } };

    for ( const auto &p : m1 ) 
    {
        std::cout << p.first << '\t' << p.second << std::endl;
    }

    auto to_lower_case = []( const std::pair<const std::string, int> &p )
    {
        std::string t; t.reserve( p.first.size() );
        std::transform( p.first.begin(), p.first.end(),
                        std::back_inserter( t ), ::tolower );
        return std::make_pair( t, p.second );                        
    };

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::map<std::string, int> m2;

    std::transform( m1.begin(), m1.end(), 
                    std::inserter( m2, m2.begin() ), to_lower_case );

    for ( const auto &p : m2 ) 
    {
        std::cout << p.first << '\t' << p.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
FIRST   1
SECOND  2

first   1
second  2
```

In the program there are used `std::transform` two times.